# Why does Jon reference the Dornishman's Wife?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

**SPOILERS FOR PEOPLE WHO HAVE NOT READ *A STORM OF SWORDS*. TURN BACK NOW. YOU'VE BEEN WARNED**

OK, So when the wildlings tried attacking The Wall and the Night's Watch pushed them back (or so it seems from where I am) Jon screams

> When they break, they break hard, Jon Snow thought as he watched them reel away. The drums had all gone silent. How do you like that music, Mance? How do you like the taste of the Dornishman's wife? "Do we have anyone hurt?" he asked`

I don't get the reference to the Dornishman's wife. Can someone please tell me what that means?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe that's a reference to when Mance sang that song for Jon, when Jon was their captive.

It's a somewhat morbid [song](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_Dornishman%27s_Wife) about a man who kisses someone's wife, and is killed by the husband, but considers it a worthy trade.